# Find a regular function $f$ satisfying Re $(f) =u$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

$$u = 2x^3 - 6xy^2$$

How does one do this?

I can find a function $f(0) = i$

Not sure what this is asking me to do...

Comment: What does $u$ mean?

Comment: I do apologise. u = 2x^3 - 6xy^2

Comment: You want an analytic function $f(x+iy) = u+iv$ where $u$ is as given?  You could try the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say $z=x+iy$ and $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $u,v$ are real functions. You need to make sure the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied:

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}\end{cases}$

Since $u=2x^3-6xy^2\Rightarrow\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}=6x^2-6y^2=\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}\Rightarrow v=\displaystyle\int(6x^2-6y^2)\,\text{d}y\;+\phi(x)=6x^2y-2y^3+\phi(x)$. We are adding a function $\phi(x)$ because when doing $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ we would get rid of $\phi(x)$, since it doesn't depend on $y$, so just in case there was a part of $v$ not depending on $y$, we should add it.

Now you have to make sure $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}$: Try it for yourself first!

> $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-12xy$ and $-\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-12xy-\phi'(x)$, so we get $\phi'(x)=0\Rightarrow\phi(x)=C$, with $C$  a real constant. So $v=6x^2y-2y^3+C$.

Therefore

> $f(z)=f(x+iy)=2x^3-6xy^2+i(6x^2y-2y^3+C)=2(x^3-3xy^2+3ix^2y-iy^3)+iC=2(x+iy)^3+iC=2z^3+iC$

If we also impose $f(0)=i$ then

> $f(0)=20^3+iC=i\Rightarrow C=1$

So the final answer is

> $f(z)=2z^3+i$

Comment: Seems like this satifies the equation f(0) = i,
I need to find a function Re(f) = u

Comment: It does that too. Note that if we expand the expression of the function $f(z)=2z^3+i$ we get back to $f(z)=2x^3-6xy^2+i(6x^2y-2y^3+1)$, so $\text{Re}(f)=2x^3-6xy^2=u$.

Comment: I just wrote $f(z)=2z^3+i$ because it's a more compact notation. The fact that it's possible to do it comes precisely from forcing $f$ to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks!

Comment: How about if we want to find a function that satisfies f(0) = 3i ?

Comment: Same thing imposing $f(0)=3i$, which gives us $C=3$

Comment: So the final answer would be f(z) = 2z^3 + 3i ?

Comment: Yes, which makes sense, since we didn't have to change the real part of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

If
$f=u+iv$, then $u_x=v_y$. So
$$
u=2x^3-6xy^2\quad\Longrightarrow\quad u_x=6x^2-6y^2=v_y
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad v=6x^2y-2y^3+h(x)
$$
But $v_x=-u_y$ and hence $h'(x)=0$, and thus $h(x)=c$.
So
$$
f(x+iy)=2x^3-6xy^2+i(6x^2y-2y^3+c)
$$
Since $f(0)=i$, then c=1, and finally
$$
f(x+iy)=2x^3-6xy^2+i(6x^2y-2y^3+1)
$$

Comment: Seems like this satifies the equation f(0) = i, I need to find a function Re(f) = u